# C/C++ volatile variable accessed from another module

Tags: c, volatile

I know and understand the purpose of volatile variables and optimisation in general (well, I think I do!).  This question relates specifically to what happens if a variable is accessed outside the module it is declared in.

In the following scenario, if `funcThatWaits` was called inside bar.c, it could be optimised and not fetch the value of `sTheVar` each loop iteration.

However, when `GetTheVar` is called externally could the same optimisation apply or does the function call ensure `sTheVar` will always be read each loop iteration?

I am not suggesting this is good code or practice, but an example for the sake of the question.

bar.h

```
int GetTheVar(void);
```

bar.c

```
static /*volatile*/ int sTheVar;

int GetTheVar(void)
{
    return sTheVar;
}

static void someISROrFuncCalledFromAnotherThread(void)
{
    sTheVar = 1;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include "bar.h"

void funcThatWaits(void)
{
    while(GetTheVar() != 1) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when `GetTheVar` is called externally could the same optimisation apply or does the function call ensure `sTheVar` will always be read each loop iteration?

The same optimization may apply. For instance, if you are using LTO (Link-Time Optimization), then the compiler knows everything about `GetTheVar` and will likely decide `funcThatWaits` is an infinite loop (which, by the way, would be UB).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have two answers, one saying will be optimised, another saying wont be.  Do you have any reference to a standard or documentation to say it will be optimised?

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are not going to be optimized away since, for all the caller knows, the function being called could depend on some exogenous state.

I compiled the following three files using gcc:

foo.c

```
#include "bar.h"

void funcThatWaits(void) {
    while ( getVar() != 1 );
}
```

bar.c

```
#include "foo.h"

static int theVar;

int getTheVar(void) {
    return theVar;
}

void theFunc(void) {
    funcThatWaits();
}
```

test.c

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    theFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling those three into a.out and running `objdump -d a.out`, the following comes out:

```
00000000000005fa <main>:
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   e8 25 00 00 00          callq  628 <theFunc>
 603:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 608:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 609:   c3                      retq   

000000000000060a <funcThatWaits>:
 60a:   55                      push   %rbp
 60b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 60e:   90                      nop
 60f:   e8 08 00 00 00          callq  61c <getTheVar>
 614:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 617:   75 f6                   jne    60f <funcThatWaits+0x5>
 619:   90                      nop
 61a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 61b:   c3                      retq   

000000000000061c <getTheVar>:
 61c:   55                      push   %rbp
 61d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 620:   8b 05 ee 09 20 00       mov    0x2009ee(%rip),%eax        # 201014 <theVar>
 626:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 627:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000628 <theFunc>:
 628:   55                      push   %rbp
 629:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 62c:   e8 d9 ff ff ff          callq  60a <funcThatWaits>
 631:   90                      nop
 632:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 633:   c3                      retq   
 634:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 63b:   00 00 00 
 63e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have two answers, one saying will be optimised, another saying wont be.  Do you have any reference to a standard or documentation to say it wont be optimised?